# Regex lookaround (?![\+\.])

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to look for instances with `C` or `c` not followed by `+` and also including the one located at the end of the string.

The answer regex from the online class is as following;

```
pattern = r'\b[Cc]\b(?![\+\.])'
```

But I don't understand why it cannot be like this;

```
pattern = r'\b[Cc](?!+.)'
```

Can anyone explain why?

Much appreciated if you can enlighten me!

Comment: Have you tried your `\b[Cc](?!+.)` regex? It has [syntax issues](https://regex101.com/r/SUEgQ8/1).

Comment: Duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it says 'nothing to repeat'

Comment: Correct. You can't quantify `(?!`. You might have tried `r'\b[Cc]\b(?!\+|\.)'` though. `(?!\+|\.)` will work the same as `(?![+.])`

Comment: Thanks. `r'\b[Cc]\b(?!\+|\.)'` works. Just for clarification, inside the parenthesis of `(?!\+|\.)` what is `'\'`  for? Is it to escape from the quantifier role?

Comment: `+` is a quantifier, `\+` is a literal `+` char, see [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Undertstood Wiktor. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please agree with the dupe status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original regex can be simplified to `\b[Cc]\b(?!\+)` i.e.:

- the negative lookahead should contain only (escaped) `+`,
- so brackets are not needed.

When you try the above regex on `xxx c- c# c! c+ ac ca xxx c`:

- first 3 occurrences of `c` are matched, as:

  - before them there is a word boundary,
  - after them there is also a word boundary ("-", "#" and "!" are
    not word chars),
  - after them there are no "+" (forbidden by the negative lookahead),
- fourth occurrence (`c+`) is not matched (the lookahead failed),
- fifth occurrence (`ac`) is not matched (no word boundary before "c"),
- sixth occurrence (`ca`) is not matched (no word boundary after "c"),
- the seventh occurrence (terminal `c`) is matched (word boundary before,
  word boundary after, no `-` after).

And now let's look at your second regex. It should not contain any dot
after `+`. Another correction is that `+` must be escaped, otherwise
there is regex error. So your second pattern should be corrected to:
`\b[Cc](?!\+)`:

- it also contains word boundary (`\b`) before,
- but now word boundary is required after it,
- it also contains the negative lookahead as before.

This time the sixth occurrence of `c` in my test string is also matched,
because the second pattern doesn't require any word boundary after `c`.

So to sum up, it is up to you whether you require the word boundary after `c`.
Actually, you wrote `instances with "C" or "c" not followed by "+"`,
so there is no requirement for word boundary after "c" and the second
pattern (after my corrections) is also OK.

I advise you to use online regex tester at https://regex101.com/,
as it contains good explanations concerning the pattern tried.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. Appreciate it